# How to add a cookie based authenticationScheme in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core

I'd like to use the `[Authorize]` attribute in my controller classes to redirect users who are not signed in, to my sign in page.  For authentication, I'd like to keep it simple and just use a session variable to track if someone is signed in or not.

I tried adding authentication to my startup class:

```
services.AddAuthentication()
            .AddCookie(options =>
            {
                options.AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/Account/SignIn");
                options.LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/SignIn");
                options.LogoutPath = new PathString("/Home/SignOut");
            });
```

but am getting the error when I go to a controller with the `[Authorize]` attribute:

> InvalidOperationException: No authenticationScheme was specified, and there was no DefaultChallengeScheme found.

So how does one set up an authenticationScheme or use a default one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the default AuthenticationScheme.

As the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?view=aspnetcore-2.2#configuration) says

> AuthenticationScheme passed to AddAuthentication sets the default
>   authentication scheme for the app.

In your case

```
services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddCookie(options =>
            {
                options.AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/Account/SignIn");
                options.LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/SignIn");
                options.LogoutPath = new PathString("/Home/SignOut");
            });
```